# Infopath 2010 "Data Connection Wizard" can't find Sharepoint Library or list

Tags: infopath, forms-services

i have an infopath form on a sharepoint list. it works fine. i've added data connections to the list before. i've not worked on the form in a while, and just now realized that i'm no longer allowed to add data connections using the wizard, to a sharepoint list.

i get "The operation could not be complete" with no additional information.

i AM able to add a Field of lookup type to a sharepoint list, but that doesn't help me because it only surfaces the ID and Title fields and i need to be able to query the list connection using other parameters.

i looked in the sharepoint logs and couldn't see anything obvious.

any ideas how to get this functionality back??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have root site for your site collection? It your site collection has only sub site then you need to create root site also to open sub site in InfoPath 2010.

Comment: this was the answer. i'd deleted it because i don't need a site there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a root level site collection. It will work.

Comment: Can you please extend this answer, why will it work, and why is it not working as is? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not changed the proxy settings in IE right? Ensure you can navigate to your SP site using your default browser (IE e.g.)